# Should a dev team use a local database or a remote shared one?

Tags: oracle-11g

I'm part of a team of developer and today, we do our developments against an Oracle 11g database installed on our own machine each.
I would like to know your point of view about this way of working compared to working with one single Oracle instance, installed on a virtual machine, hosting one schema per developer ? Knowing that one schema represents today more or less 20Gb of data.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

> What do you think ?

Use whichever configuration is best suited to your environment. For example, your application might not understand schemas so each developer might need their own database.

At work I have both. My local database allows me to do whatever I want whenever I need to, while the remote shared database is used in conjunction with an external system. The data in the shared database needs to be kept in sync with this external system, so each developer taking a copy and running it locally would not work.